# WooCommerce New order email manually trigger for some products

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I need to know  WooCommerce new order email to given email address for only in specific products.

Ex: if any body buy a product **X** need a new order email to **Y**. The **Y** is not set in as back end Recipient. Is there any hook to achieve this ?

I tried follow

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_woocommerce_order_status_completed' );
function custom_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        if($value == 10) { // given product id
            // trigger order complete email for specific email address
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the following in your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);

function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $object) {
    $recipient = $recipient . ', me@myemail.com';
    return $recipient;
}
```

the only drawback is that the recipient will see both your address & his own in the To: field.

---

Alternatively, you can use the woocommerce_email_headers filter. the $object passed allows you to only apply this to the completed order email:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'mycustom_headers_filter_function', 10, 2);

function mycustom_headers_filter_function( $headers, $object ) {
    if ($object == 'customer_completed_order') {
        $headers .= 'BCC: My name <my@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    }

    return $headers;
}
```

Taken from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92030/102229) from [Ewout](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26106/ewout).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13572897)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - edited my answer to include the code snippets directly.

Comment: Is there any reason why when using a default email sent after checkout occurs that this hook might not work?  I've used your first example and concatenated on an extra email, but it still only sends it to the buyer only.  I even tried to bump up the priority to see if that had any effect and it doesn't.

Comment: Does this hook even exist anymore?  Can't find it in woocommerce plugin just in stackoverflow answers that are about a year old.