# woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order hook not being invoked

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There are a bunch of [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327088/woocommerce-new-order-email-manually-trigger-for-some-products) of using this woocommerce hook `woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order`. So I added it to functions.php, and concatenated a couple example recipients as a test, but only the purchaser receives an email.  It doesn't seem like this filter is getting invoked since if I turn on debugging and `error_log(...)` there's nothing in the log file.

Is there a reason this isn't working?  I tried bumping the priority up to 99, but that doesn't work either.  The site uses all the defaults and doesn't override any of the templates.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'custom_woocommerce_add_email_recipient', 10, 2);
function custom_woocommerce_add_email_recipient($recipient, $order) {
    $recipient = $recipient . ', foo@example.com, bar@example.com';
    return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: Kindly, this is not the good behavior and the fair way, so anyway I delete my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I learn more about Woocommerce it looks like this site only goes as far as processing so I had to use the `customer_processing_order` mail ID instead to get this to work (thanks to @LoicTheAztec for verifying the `customer_completed_order` hook works), and instead of using the `woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order` hook I used `woocommerce_email_headers` and checked the mail ID.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'woocommerce_email_headers_add_recipient', 10, 3);
function woocommerce_email_headers_add_recipient($headers, $mail_id, $order) {
    if($mail_id == 'customer_processing_order') {
        $member = null;
        $memberMail = null;
        foreach($order->get_meta_data() as $item) {
            if ($item->key === 'member_name') {
                $member = $item->value;
                $memberMail = $this->getMemberMail($member);
                $headers .= "BCC: {$member} <{$member_mail}>\r\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $headers;
}
```